# Setting up shared Variables in dynamic library

Tags: c, global-variables, extern

I created a logging library `liblog.so`. I want to share a variable called `File *rt_file` it's defined in `lib_rt.h` and also this header inherited by `log_rt.c,log_linux.c ==> liblog.so`,`logd.c ==> logd` and also `log_rt_client.c ==> log_rt_client`. Here i created a daemon `logd` which puts(actually should) `file pointer` `rt_file`.

That's what i want to do. 
Here `liblog.so` is a dynamic libarary, `logd` starts on boot up and it should set file pointer to `rt_file` and `log_rt_client` should get the file pointer and print some logs.

Problem comes to share the common variable `rt_file`. 
I tried other suggestions suggested in

stackoverflow [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-share-a-variable-between-source-files-in-c-with-extern-but-how): first solution was to use `extern` and complete the task. For my situation i though for [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10355339/how-to-share-a-variable-and-its-value-between-many-source-file-in-c-language) this. Rather than making a global variable put the variable to scoped file and use `get` and `set` functions to access the values.

but both options didn't worked for me let me Explain.

1. I (Have to)compiled all the files `liblog.so` `logd` and `log_rt_client` separately so, it was showing error when `log_rt_client` had declaration of `rt_file` but not defined because it's defined in `logd`. which was not(can't) compiled with `log_rt_client`. Though all the files linked to `liblog.so`
2. When i tried second options, results were unexpected, `logd` calls to `liblog.so` set's and get's the file pointer but when i ran `log_rt_client` `rt_file` doesn't had the expected pointer(File pointer). Means allocation for `rt_file` for both are differen.

Can any one suggest me a solution. Hope this explains everything.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use shared memory

Dynamic lib is mapped into process address space, So each process will see their copy 
of rt_file mapped into their data segment  (i mean any global variable. in your case it is rt_file).